# Remove node from multisites?

Tags: php, functions, customization, multisite

I have a function which looks like below, where the goal is to remove New Post and Manage Comments from the "My Sites" dropdown. This works well if I replace {$node_id} with a blogs id. But I want this to work for all multisites you have in your "My sites" list. That means I need to get all the blog id's.
This is how far I have come, but it doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_nodes_from_mysites', 999 );
function remove_nodes_from_mysites( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $blog_ids = get_sites();

    foreach($blog_ids as $key) {
        foreach($key as $k => $val) {
            $node_id = $k['blog_id'];

            $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( "blog-{$node_id}-n" );
            $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( "blog-{$node_id}-c" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this:

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_nodes_from_mysites', 999 );
function remove_nodes_from_mysites( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( get_current_user_id() );
    foreach ( $user_blogs as $user_blog ) {
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( "blog-" . $user_blog->userblog_id . "-n" );
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( "blog-" . $user_blog->userblog_id . "-c" );
    }
}
```